# How do i translate this c# code into java

Tags: java, c#, translate

I'm trying to test a De-Casteljau-subdivision code. However my example is in c# and i want to test it in java as I don't know c#.

Especially the last return gives me issues as i cant get it right.
I use Vec2D instead of point representing basic 2d vectors. In this case i represent the points with a Vec2D array. I have methods like "getX" to get the x part but if i just change it in the last line it fails.
To sum it up i exchanged "Point" with Vec2D[] and p1.X with p1.getX.

```
private void drawCasteljau(List<point> list)
{
    Point tmp;
    for (double t = 0; t & lt;= 1; t += 0.001) {
        tmp = getCasteljauPoint(points.Count - 1, 0, t);
        image.SetPixel(tmp.X, tmp.Y, color);
    }
}

private Point getCasteljauPoint(int r, int i, double t)
{
    if (r == 0) return points[i];

    Point p1 = getCasteljauPoint(r - 1, i, t);
    Point p2 = getCasteljauPoint(r - 1, i + 1, t);

    return new Point((int)((1 - t) * p1.X + t * p2.X), (int)((1
                             - t) * p1.Y + t * p2.Y));
}
```

My attempt:

```
public Vec2D[] getCasteljauPoint(int r, int i, double t) { 
    if(r == 0) return new Vec2D[i];

    Vec2D[] p1 = getCasteljauPoint(r - 1, i, t);
    Vec2D[] p2 = getCasteljauPoint(r - 1, i + 1, t);


    return new Vec2D(((1/2) * p1.getX + (1/2) * p2.getX),  ((1/2)                        
                        * p1.getY + (1/2) * p2.getY));
}
```

I feel like there should be just minor changes to get it going but im stuck. Error message on last line says
- getX cannot be resolved or is not a field
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Vec2D to Vec2D[]

Comment: You're declaring everything (return value, variables within your method) as `Vec2D[]`.  This would be an _array_ of `Vec2D` objects.  So when you try to return a _single_ `Vec2D` (not single element in an array) that's a type mismatch.  Additionally, this is why `p1.getX` isn't an option as arrays do not have a `getX` field.  `p1[0].getX` _might_ work, although at a guess (I don't know what class `Vec2D` is), `getX` would be a _method_, not a field, and so would be invoked `p1[0].getX()`.  But as a first pass, I'd stop everything being arrays.

Comment: What is the benefit of avoiding Java’s [Point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Point.html) class, when you’re just going to use it to set pixels in an image?  By using Point, the code will look nearly identical to the C# version, which will greatly reduce the likelihood of introducing bugs.

Comment: Well that makes sense. Im trying to identify points as a Vec2D array. This code uses a de-Casteljau algorithm to get new points. I use Vec2D array because i have written that class already and want to keep going with it and it also supports my drawing method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `p1` and `p2` as `Vec2D` arrays and your method definition specifies a `Vec2D` array return type. However, inside your method you return a singlar `Vec2D` object.

A potential solution:

```
public class SomeJavaClassName 
{ 
    ArrayList<Vec2D> points = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Other methods, properties, variables, etc.,
    // some of which would populate points

    public Vec2D getCasteljauPoint(int r, int i, double t) { 
        // points[] is declared outside just like in the C# code
        if(r == 0) return points.get(i);

        Vec2D p1 = getCasteljauPoint(r - 1, i, t);
        Vec2D p2 = getCasteljauPoint(r - 1, i + 1, t);

        return new Vec2D(((1/2) * p1.getX + (1/2) * p2.getX), ((1/2)
                            * p1.getY + (1/2) * p2.getY));
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense a lot. I made a mistake: its getX() but that can be adjusted. 1 question remains: the c# code uses point list to represent the points. I want to use Vec2D[]. How can i handle that "return points[i]"?

Comment: Or can i do just the same if i use an array list?

Comment: @Urlaka You got it: you would use an `ArrayList` and then `return points.get(i);` instead of `return points[i];`